# Bluetooth Ubuntu A405DL cell phone pairing mode

Tags: bluetooth

How can I use Bluetooth in pairing mode to connect Ubuntu and A405DL cell phone?

Comment: Just like any other Bluetooth device.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bluetooth transmission possible between Linux and a cell phone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411312/bluetooth-transmission-possible-between-linux-and-a-cell-phone)